# Pros/cons of service account and service principal in AAD

Tags: security, entra-id

The official Microsoft docs [strongly discourage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/service-accounts-governing-azure) the practice of user accounts employed as service accounts. Instead, they recommend using service principals or managed identities.

Leaving aside MI's for the time being, I just had a question about this. Why is there such a strong recommendation against user accounts as service accounts in AAD? Consider the alternative of a service principal:

- Both require some kind of secret to authenticate, whether a user password or client secret. Since this is a service account that won't see interactive use, presumably we can generate a strong random password for it, so the level of security should be the same.
- A service principal requires application permissions in AAD, which are very strong due to not being linked to a specific identity. Eg if I give my app the Files.ReadWrite permission, I can mess with the OneDrives of ALL users in my org. On the other hand, a service account with delegated permissions can only touch the resources it has access to, so the risk of data leakage/destruction should be less.
- The service account uses the [resource owner password](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow to authenticate, which isn't supported by all auth providers. Still, if I'm only using pure AAD this won't be a problem.

Why are service accounts considered harmful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am with you on this one.
I did this kind of research myself and came to the same conclusion: currently service accounts are much secure option than service principals.

Major issues with service principals are:

- lack of permissions granularity
- lack of Azure AD Conditional Access rules support
- weak actions logging

The only real benefit I found for using service principal, is that you don't need a license to access Office 365 data, like files or emails. This has nothing to do with security though.

To be fair, I guess certificate authentication scenario is a valid case of distinct security feature which is not available for AAD service accounts. But again, there are no means to secure service principals any further